# I haven't figured out how to decode this 42x5 QR code like data

Tags: qr-code, decoding

[Qr code like data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJUKA.png)

I'm not sure what i'm looking for here but this Qr code like data does not want to make sense.

Comment: This looks similar to a slice or truncated version of PDF417 https://www.scandit.com/products/barcode-scanning/symbologies/pdf417/ are you 100% sure it is properly formed? Otherwise this might be a proprietary format, which would explain the lack of documentation, it's not meant for you to decode

Comment: It's probably not PDF417 since there are no stripes at the end. Looked at first like [iQR](http://barcodeguide.seagullscientific.com/Content/Symbologies/iQR.htm) but missing the eye. I think it's proprietary.